# Python replace '\' with '/' where '\' is followed by 't'

Tags: python, string, replace, backslash

How to replace all backslashes with slashes in a string where at least one backslash is immediately followed by the character `'t'`?
I use `replace('\\', '/')`, but the `'\t'` is interpreted as tab and it is not replaced.

Example:

```
'D:\myfiles\test'.replace('\\','/')
```

Output:

```
'D:/myfiles\test'
```

Similar things happen with combinations like `'\f'`, `'\n'`, etc.

Comment: `\t` is one character, a tab. It is just shown as two. You can not access the backslash individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\t` , `\f`, `\n`, etc. are escape sequences. So, whenever you need to use them in a string, you need to use \\ instead of \.

In your case, you should do

```
'D:\\myfiles\\test'.replace('\\','/')
```

Comment: When you need a literal backslash you should ALWAYS double them up, don't try to guess whether the character following the backslash is special or not.  So the example would be `'D:\\myfiles\\test'`.

Comment: @CATboardBETA r-strings are great, but did you know you can't put a backslash as the last character?

Comment: @MarkRansom Awesome!

Comment: Assuming that the string is entered by the user as it is, i.e. single backslashes, is there a solution other than going over the characters one by one to replace them with slashes?

Comment: @Ana if the string is truly "entered by the user" e.g. read from the console, the sequence `\t` should be two separate characters and the `replace` call should work fine on it.  It's only string literals contained in your code that will have `\t` replaced with a single tab character.